# Asynchtask with splashScreen

Tags: android, android-asynctask

i want to murge between splash screen with shown first with asynchtask on my application , i start with splash 5 seconde , then asynchtask , i want that when i start my splash also asynchtask start to load , this is my splash code :

```
public class SplashActivity extends Activity {

    private static String Spsc = SplashActivity.class.getName();
    private static long time = 5;   
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE); 
        this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);  // Removes notification bar
        setContentView(R.layout.splash);
        IntentLauncher launcher = new IntentLauncher();
        launcher.start();
    }
    private class IntentLauncher extends Thread {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(time*1000);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e(Spsc, e.getMessage());
            }
            Intent intent = new Intent(SplashActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
            SplashActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
            SplashActivity.this.finish();
        }
    }
}
```

and this is my splash from mainActivity :

```
class FetchPosts extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        private ProgressDialog progressDialog;
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {         
            super.onPreExecute();
            progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this, "", getString(R.string.loading_message));
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            articles = Services.getPosts(MainActivity.this);

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);

            progressDialog.dismiss();

        }
    }
```

Comment: What is your question? What is/isn't working?

Comment: this is 2 activities, and i want to murge between them the splash shown and in the same time asynchtask load data .

Comment: That I understand. What am I asking is what happens/doesn't happen now when you run it? We know what you want. What we don't know is what isn't working about it. Also, probably want to put your `AsyncTask` as an inner class of your `MainActivity` if it isn't already or at least execute it from `MainActivity`

Comment: i explain to you , this asynchtask is just a part of my main , and this splash firstly i use it alone in an acitvity then the man show lather , but what i want that tha splash show while the asynchtask start, and just for the first time because i will use other activities

Answer (score 0):

Simply

```
 public class SplashActivity extends Activity {

private static String Spsc = SplashActivity.class.getName();
private static long time = 5;   
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE); 
    this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);  // Removes notification bar
    setContentView(R.layout.splash);
    IntentLauncher launcher = new IntentLauncher();
    launcher.start();
}
private class IntentLauncher extends Thread {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(time*1000);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(Spsc, e.getMessage());
        }
        //Intent intent = new Intent(SplashActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
        //SplashActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
        //SplashActivity.this.finish();
          new FetchPosts().execute();
    }
   }
public class FetchPosts extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    private ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {         
        super.onPreExecute();
        progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this, "", getString(R.string.loading_message));
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        articles = Services.getPosts(MainActivity.this);

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);

        progressDialog.dismiss();

    }
 }
}
```

Comment: should i use the class on the mainActivity or what ? it's murge between two activities ?

Comment: if you are calling `MainActivity.java` only to execute `AsyncTask` than now you don't nee that class cause `new FetchPosts().execute();`  this will `AsyncTask`

Answer (score 0):

try the following code it will start the asynctask when the splashscreen acctivity is started

```
public class SplashActivity extends Activity {

private static String Spsc = SplashActivity.class.getName();
private static long time = 5;   
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE); 
    this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);  // Removes notification bar
    setContentView(R.layout.splash);
    FetchPosts obj=new FetchPosts();
    obj.execute("dummystring");
 }
}

class FetchPosts extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    private ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {         
        super.onPreExecute();
        progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this, "", getString(R.string.loading_message));
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
        articles = Services.getPosts(MainActivity.this);

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);

        progressDialog.dismiss();

    }
}
```

Comment: @Kira replace the first and third void with String after AsyncTask<> and also make parameter of doInBackground(String...params)

Comment: i try it , but nothing happened :(